# Why does my main water supply go down into the foundation?

Tags: plumbing

The main water supply in our house comes up out of the foundation then sends cold water in four directions--the bathroom, the kitchen, the water heater, and back into the foundation.

I know why we need water in those first three places, but can someone tell me where the water might be going in pipe that re-enters the foundation?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly to an outside faucet. Possibly to another out building if you have such.

Comment: In my house, I also have one going back into the foundation.  It leads to a basement wet bar in the next room.  The alternative would be plumbing up to the ceiling and then back down (adding a pillar to the bar to hide it).  Do you have something similar?

Comment: The foundation... or the floor?

Answer (score 1):

This is very common, but not good. It's not good because it's under the concrete slab & expensive to get to, as well, these do usually fail very prematurely & first (30 to 60-years) because they live in harsh & moist conditions to be constantly under attack.

But, this is "normal" for basement baths & laundry sinks or laundry supply hook-ups. It was just cheaper, easier & shorter to run the pipes this way. A lazy Plumber that didn't care about the future & a crap builder that went along with it...just like today.

If you're saddled with a leak in the future, that's when you should see if you can run that piping up into walls, across ceilings & back down walls instead...unless you're doing renovations that can correct it sooner. This will double the piping's lifespan & be easily repaired in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The PVC pipe from my well pump does the same thing - exits right out of the floor on the way to the pressure tank.  In my case, the purpose is to keep the water from freezing as the floor in the utility room is at outside grade.

Most likely in your situation a wall entry point 5 ft below grade would not be practical.

(Side note - I want to add a 4 season buried  water supply to another building, but I'd need to start by going down into the slap within the utility room.  A bit more than my tools can handle!)

Comment: Did you mean "down into the slab...."? I almost edited it but then realized you may mean something else.